# Memory usage is different between SetLength() and GetMem()?

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi XE8 to test the `SetLength()` and `GetMem()` procedures.

Code to test `SetLength()`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: array of Byte;
begin
  SetLength(a,100*1024*1024); //100Mb
  ShowMessage('See Task Manager');
  SetLength(a,0);
end;
```

Task Manager shows the memory usage of `Project1.exe` is ~100Mb.

[image]

Code to test `GetMem()`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  p: PByte;
begin
  GetMem(p,100*1024*1024); //100Mb
  ShowMessage('See Task Manager');
  FreeMem(p);
end;
```

Task Manager shows the memory usage of `Project1.exe` is ~2Mb.

[image]

Task Manager shows the correct memory usage when using `SetLength()`. My questions: Is `SetLength()` better than `GetMem()`?

This is my test:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/r0dfb99mlc8h1jj/DelphiTest.rar/file

Comment: Perhaps you are mistaken.  I cant test it on XE8, just tried on D11.  I suspect you are reading the wrong column in task manager.

Comment: It's interesting that you ask for 100MB and get 2MB, and think that this is better than asking for 100MB and getting 100MB! Clearly your diagnostics are wrong. SetLength calls GetMem anyway. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Look my images, i'm not reading the wrong column in task manager

Comment: @BắcHổ What do you think that column actually means? And what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @David Heffernan Column Memory is RAM memory. I think if use `GetMem` then System can not manage RAM correct

Comment: @BắcHổ: There is definitely not a bug here: the system works perfectly. However, memory usage can be measured in many different ways, and that's confusing you. If you start to actually fill the bytes you get from `GetMem`, you'll see that you use ~100 MB. (For example: `for var i := 0 to 100*1024*1024-1 do PByte(p)[i] := 12;`)

Comment: Nope. Virtual memory is much more complicated than your mental model. Whatever is going on here, it's not an issue with GetMem or SetLength, the latter of which calls the former. Again, what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Ok! Fill the bytes is solve my problem. Thanks @Andreas Rejbrand

Comment: SetLength uses FillChar to clear allocated memory. When I stepped through FIllChar in the debugger, the memory usage appeared in the task manager.

Comment: Your problem is that you think when a program allocates a block of memory, then that memory is automatically a part of the RAM column. It isn't. Only when you start to USE the memory does it in fact get physically allocated to your task (in 4K blocks). If you allocate 100Mb and only fill 10Mb of it with data, you'll only consume 10 Mb of memory. Only when you have touched at least one byte in each 4K block of the 100Mb does your program actually "own" the full 100Mb of memory. (The 4K may be 64K in some operating systems on modern CPUs with lots of RAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Windows Taskmanager is telling you a value for a different memory (possibly Used, instead of Allocated).  I get the same results as you do when using TaskManager.

However, I don't normally use that, I use SysteInternal's Process Explorer.

In teh shots, Application is called **GetMem**, Process Explorer shows the correct figure. First column is **Virtual Size** and the second **Private Bytes**.  They both increase by 100M.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image]

And **SetLength** shows similar figures.  That is, as far as Delphi is considered, the memory usage is the same, as it should be.